# How does JPA enforce OneOnOne relationship for entities?

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink, one-to-one

I have the following pseudo entities

```
public class Child {

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="PARENT_ID")
    private Parent parent;

}

public class Parent {

    @OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="parent",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private Child child;

}
```

Database:

```
PARENT
PARENT_ID, PARENT_NAME
1        , "John"
2        , "Bob"

CHILD
ID, PARENT_ID
1 , 1
2 , 2
```

Now I load Parent 1 from the DB, and get Child 1 accordingly. But then I set Child 1 parent to Parent 2 and commit changes. Child 1 PARENT_ID changes to 2, but Child 2 still also has PARENT_ID 2. So DB looks like this:

```
CHILD
ID, PARENT_ID
1 , 2
2 , 2
```

Is there a way for JPA to detect, given the OneToOne relationship, that Parent 2 has been reassigned to child 1 and make Child 2's parent null?

Running EclipseLink

Comment: Since Child 1 still references parent 1, which one is 'right'? If you need Child1 to reference null or a different parent, those decisions are left to the application logic. You can prevent both referencing the same parent by setting the parent_ID to have a unique constraint.

Comment: I had hoped in the same way that orphanRemoval will delete a child row even if you don't specifically call for it that there was a way OneOnOne would know to remove the reference from the old child entity when you assign the parent to the new one.

Comment: EJB 1.0 tried that, and it caused more problems then it solved (IMO). JPA simplified things so that other then a few things (likely lazy fetching) entities are just POJOs and only do what you make them do.